# i am trying to fetch data from mysql to node.js here is the issue

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

here is the issue
this is my query

```
SELECT * from employee_leaves 
WHERE employee_leave_company_name ='$sup_company_name' AND leave_status='Pending'
ORDER BY employee_leave_id desc";
```

the problem here is `employee_leave_company_name` is stored in php variable `$sup_company_name` in my file `require.php`
so how should i access that variable in my javascript

this is what i have done so far

```
var cmpny_name;
var reqData=["c_name" : "sup_company_name"];
var xhrObj = $.get("require.php",c_name)
.done(function( response ) { 
  cmpny_name=response;//The echo text from server
})
.fail(function() {
  alert('error'); 
});
```

but this isnt working....
   and here is my php code from require.php

```
$sup_company_name=$_SESSION['employee_company_name'];
```

Comment: So, you're not echo'ing the result in the `require.php` file?

Comment: @Epodax no i am not echoing it in my require php file

Comment: Javascript can't fetch data from a php variable, you need to echo it from php.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var cmpny_name;
var reqData=["c_name" : "<?php echo $sup_company_name; ?>";
var xhrObj = $.get("require.php",c_name)
.done(function( response ) { 
  cmpny_name=response;//The echo text from server
})
.fail(function() {
  alert('error'); 
});
```

Other than this, if you really want to interact between PHP and JavaScript you should use Ajax.

Answer (score -1):

You must "pass" the php var value to the "client side"... so for example print a hidden input with the value in order to use then with js or something like that.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenval" name="hiddenval" value="<?php echo $sup_company_name; ?>" />
```

and then get the value from this element with js.